# Wierd Error while working with unlimited argument function Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

```
//##// Function Zone //##//
function out(type, ...strings) {
    var str = strings.join(' ');
    switch (type) {
        case "log":
            console.log("\x1b[37m", '[LOG]\t', str, "\x1b[0m");
            break;
        case "error":
            console.log("\x1b[31m",'[ERROR]\t', str, "\x1b[0m");
            break;
        case "info":
            console.log("\x1b[36m", '[INFO]\t', str, "\x1b[0m");
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('Bad output type');
    }
}
```

When I start the program it crashes with this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Error::New napi_get_last_error_info<br/>
 1: 00007FF6F206CF2F napi_wrap+112799<br/>
 2: 00007FF6F200CF26 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+55702<br/>
 3: 00007FF6F200DDB3 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+59427<br/>
 4: 00007FF6F200D509 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+57209<br/>
 5: 00007FF6F2032410 napi_fatal_error+160<br/>
 6: 00007FFC74541DA3 <br/>
 7: 00007FFC74541CF7 <br/>
 8: 00007FFC7454CB69 <br/>
 9: 00007FF6F203032C node_module_register+1548<br/>
10: 00007FF6F20BD340 uv_timer_stop+560<br/>
11: 00007FF6F20BD417 uv_timer_stop+775<br/>
12: 00007FF6F20B9ECB uv_async_send+331<br/>
13: 00007FF6F20B966C uv_loop_init+1212<br/>
14: 00007FF6F20B9834 uv_run+244<br/>
15: 00007FF6F1FC9681 v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayWriter::source_position_table_builder+31713<br/>
16: 00007FF6F2036223 node::Start+275<br/>
17: 00007FF6F1EB6A9C RC4_options+340380<br/>
18: 00007FF6F2D2F3F8 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+1300536<br/>
19: 00007FFCB7CA7034 BaseThreadInitThunk+20<br/>
20: 00007FFCB7DDCEC1 RtlUserThreadStart+33<br/>
```

Any Idea?
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Are you getting that error from just declaring the function? If not, how are you calling it?

Comment: i tried your function and it works well using this input out("log", ["ezrzser", "ddds"]);

Comment: That error looks like an internal problem in your Node installation, and it probably has nothing whatsoever to do with the code you posted.

Comment: @Pointy I will try to update my node installation

Comment: @Bergi This is an example about how i used it: out("info", "Web Server loaded") it prints that and then crashes

Comment: @ChamsddineBouzaine If updating node installation won't work, I'll do it like you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, I forgot to modify a function in my code, the error is because of that. I called the method info() that is a standard node.js method an that caused the error.

Thank you anyway :D